# How to download some HTML pages so I can quickly view all of them offline?

Tags: download, html, viewer

I need some help with some [research](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&num=100&q=silverlight+success+story&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) I'm doing, where I need to refer to many online pages. Now instead of opening each in a tab, I'm looking for a software that can download many HTML pages at once (I'll give it a list of URLs), and it should give me an interface to quickly switch between the offline pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/427), an extension for Firefox that downloads and organizes sites or individual pages, then allows annotation, checking for updates on original sites and has other features. It differs from other downloaders because it stores downloaded pages in its own storage (which might be a feature or drawback for you).

Its interface is very similar to standard bookmarks, so it is very easy to use.

Comment: +1 Excellent one. After opening the sidebar, under the Tools menu you have a "Capture Multiple URLs" feature, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the interface showing the pages, maybe you could make an HTML document for that which links to each one. As for downloading the list, check out [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/20/en/index.html) (available for Windows/Linux/UNIX/BSD):

[image]

There is also [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) which has ports available for most platforms. Using the `-i` switch you can provide it with a list of files to download (each on a separate line in the file):

```
wget -i files.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried the Opera browser? It has a "sessions" feature that lets you save your current session with all tabs & browsing history for each tab. The session can then be easily reopened as it was when last saved.

Unfortunately, there isn't a direct way to export your sessions, but if you dig around in your user profile, you can find them. They're saved as xml files, so you can back them up if desired.

Comment: Firefox can do this too. Using a Firefox addon like Session Manager you can manage the set of sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was unaware of that add-on. From the Mozilla page, it looks like the Firefox add-in is more flexible than Opera's sessions. Opera offers you very little in the way of session management.

Answer (score 1):

Try [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). It can download multiple pages and you can customize what type of files it should downloads, and how deep it should look.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Browse-Offline](http://www.browse-offline.com), it's a freeware program for downloading a complete site in a manner of minutes.